# Discount on multiple identical items

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I am able to apply discounts in a few areas pretty easily, but one area I cannot and want to be able to is apply a 20% discount if you purchase 4 or more identical items.  Below is the current Shopping Cart rule I have.  This rule won't apply any discounts though and I don't understand why.  I've tried other things, but they either do nothing, or apply the discount on everything in the cart, not just the products in the specified Category.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?  Am I misunderstanding what Row Quantity is?  Is there another way I can do this?  Thanks.

[image: Current Shopping Cart Rule]

Comment: Row total defines the total cost or price of row item in cart .Try using Quantity in cart instead of row total.

Comment: @RohitS. Please write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Row total defines the total cost or price of row item in cart .Try using Quantity in cart instead of row total

Answer (score 1):

Magento doesn't support your case ( multiple with identical items ), you can setup product with Tier Price but not in percent. if you still want percent i think you must do via coding.